# Deleting entities from Google App Engine with dash in their name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I need delete from my DB all entities, that contain the "-" sign in the "name" prop.

What do I need to make a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in the GAE datastore with only one query, because the datastore does not support "contains" queries. Therefore, you have two options:

1. Select all entities and iterate over the result set, checking if the name contains a "-".
2. Add a new property, e.g. "nameContainsDash" to your entity and query all entities that have this property set to `true`. This property is updated every time the name is updated.

```java
...

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    nameContainsDash = name.contains("-");
}

public boolean isNameContainsDash() {
    return nameContainsDash;
}

...
```

Of course, the second option might require data migration, since the property will be `null` for existing entities.